# SFTP trigger that isn't triggering in Logic APP

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have also an SFTP trigger that isn't triggering. I added a file to the SFTP folder and nothing happens. I think I had done this successfully in the past. I have it set to to check every 3 minutes.

Edit: I found that if I clicked on the "skipped" entry that I could see the input and output links. I noticed X-Frame-Options is deny. can anyone help me to solve this issue

output is

```json
{
    "statusCode": 202,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Retry-After": "15",
        "x-ms-request-id": "1eb3db25-ce9d-4387-91fc-612e035017f7",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Date": "Thu, 03 Oct 2019 16:23:08 GMT",
        "Location": "https://logic-apis-eastus2.azure-apim.net/apim/sftp/ddd3328a306446e4b5d438eb72ca1fba/datasets/default/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile?folderId=L2N5Z2RyaXZlL2MvVXBsb2FkRW5jb3VudGVyc0ZpbGU%3d&maxFileCount=1&triggerstate=eyJGaWxlSWQiOiIiLCJTdGF0dXMiOjEsIldpbmRvd1N0YXJ0VGltZSI6IjIwMTktMTAtMDNUMTY6MjI6MTZaIiwiV2luZG93RW5kVGltZSI6IjIwMTktMTAtMDNUMTY6MjI6MTZaIiwiTGFzdFByb2Nlc3NlZEZpbGVUaW1lIjoiMjAxOS0xMC0wM1QxNjoyMjowNy4wMDAwMDAxWiIsIkxhc3RDb25mbGljdFRpbWUiOiIyMDE5LTEwLTAzVDE2OjIyOjE5LjU4Mzg0NDNaIn0%3d",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=a703f806325944e1ff92f5b6964fbc06b4fdf5647d48c76a29966c392ea989b9;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=sftp-eus2.azconn-eus2.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "Content-Length": "0",
        "Expires": "-1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons of this issue as mentioned below:

1) Check your Logic App is enabled or not.

2) The SFTP connector handles only files that are 50 MB or smaller and doesn't support message chunking.

3) Do you have the correct SFTP folder specified in your SFTP connector? Are you uploading your files to the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but I recently came across similar issue using the SFTP-SSH trigger in logic apps, and found out that it was due to me having the "Preserve Timestamp" enabled in WinSCP, the tool which I use to place the file. As a result, all the changes which I made to the file does not modify the timestamp of the file, causing logic app to skip the file.

Here is how to disable the settings as per Microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpwithssh/).

Missing results

SFTP triggers work by polling, or checking, the SFTP file system and looking for any files that changed since the last poll. SFTP managed connector triggers compare file versions using the file's last modified timestamp.

If you create, add, or update file with a timestamp that's earlier than the currently tracked last modified timestamp, the SFTP managed connector trigger won't detect this file.

So, if you use an external tool or client that creates, adds, or updates files on the SFTP server, make sure that you disable any feature in the tool or client that preserves a file's last modified timestamp.

The following table lists some commonly used tools that preserve this timestamp and the steps to disable this feature:

SFTP client Action
WinSCP  Go to Options > Preferences > Transfer > Edit > Preserve timestamp > Disable.
FileZilla   Go to Transfer > Preserve timestamps of transferred files > Disable.